# iOS Passing data collection view controller to a table view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am doing a food app and I am having a problem. I have a collection view controller which have 10 items(each one is a different dish). Each of those items have an image and a title and what i want to do is that when someone taps the item(the dish) it takes the user to a table view controller which have a list of items(ingredients) about the dish. My problem is that I don't know how to pass the data from a collection view controller to a table view controller. Here is my code:

```
***View Controller.m (collection view controller):***

@interface ViewController ()
{
  NSArray *_arrayOfImages;
  NSArray *_arrayOfNames;

  **// Array de ingredientes**
  NSArray *_arrayOfCeviche;
  NSArray *_arrayOfBrasa;
  NSArray *_arrayOfTacacho;
  NSArray *_arrayOfPachamanca;
  NSArray *_arrayOfAnticucho;
  NSArray *_arrayOfChaufa;
  NSArray *_arrayOfPapita;
  NSArray *_arrayOfParihuela;
  NSArray *_arrayOfLomo;
  NSArray *_arrayOfCuy;

  **//Array which stores all the ingredients arrays**
  NSArray *_arrayOfIngredients;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

**// Array which contain the titles**
_arrayOfNames = @[@"Anticucho", @"Arroz Chaufa", @"Cebiche", @"Pachamanca", @"Papa a la               Huancaina", @"Parihuela", @"Picante de cuy", @"Tacacho con cecina", @"Pollo a la brasa", @"Lomo saltado"];

**// Array which containe the images**
_arrayOfImages = @[@"Anticucho.jpg", @"chaufa.jpg", @"ceviche.jpg", @"pachamanca.jpg", @"papita.jpg", @"parihuela.jpg", @"cuy.jpg", @"tacacho.jpg", @"brasa.jpg", @"lomo.jpg"];

// Arrays que de los ingredientes
_arrayOfCeviche = @[@"Quesito", @"Limon", @"Choclito", @"Cocinita", @"La lechesita", @"La miradita", @"La weuabdita", @"La cagada", @"Ptm Toy Jodido XD", @"Que emoción", @"Wiiiiiii"];

_arrayOfBrasa = @[@"jamonadita", @"delicisoso", @"Sexo", @"Anal", @"Oral", @"Vaginal", @"Culantraso", @"Violenita", @"Sexo salvaje", @"Mujeres", @"Coger coger"];

_arrayOfChaufa = @[@"qUESIto", @"Jodido", @"Ala", @"Que pajita", @"Wuauau", @"Tengo hambrunita", @"jojolete", @"Sequito duro", @"Latititititito", @"Manusico"];

 **// Array which contains the other arrays**
_arrayOfIngredients = @[@"_arrayOfBrasa, _arrayOfCeviche,_arrayOfChaufa];

}

 **// Method to pass the data from a collection view controller to a table view controller**
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] objectAtIndex:0];

    DetailViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    dvc.Titulos = [_arrayOfIngredients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 }
}
```

And my table view controller code:

```
***Detail View Controller.m (table view controller):***
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
cell.textLabel.text = self.Titulos;

return cell; 
}
```

My biggest problem is the array containing the other arrays. Trying to access the _arrayOfIngredients and from it access the array of the ingredient of the selected item.

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

     **// Array which contain the titles**
      _arrayOfNames = @[@"Anticucho", @"Arroz Chaufa", @"Cebiche", @"Pachamanca", @"Papa a la Huancaina", @"Parihuela", @"Picante de cuy", @"Tacacho con cecina", @"Pollo a la brasa", @"Lomo saltado"];

     **// Array which containe the images**
      _arrayOfImages = @[@"Anticucho.jpg", @"chaufa.jpg", @"ceviche.jpg", @"pachamanca.jpg", @"papita.jpg", @"parihuela.jpg", @"cuy.jpg", @"tacacho.jpg", @"brasa.jpg", @"lomo.jpg"];

      **// Arrays que de los ingredientes**
      _arrayOfCeviche = @[@"Quesito", @"Limon", @"Choclito", @"Cocinita", @"La lechesita", @"La miradita", @"La weuabdita", @"La cagada", @"Ptm Toy Jodido XD", @"Que emoción", @"Wiiiiiii"];

      _arrayOfBrasa = @[@"jamonadita", @"delicisoso", @"Sexo", @"Anal", @"Oral", @"Vaginal", @"Culantraso", @"Violenita", @"Sexo salvaje", @"Mujeres", @"Coger coger"];

      _arrayOfChaufa = @[@"qUESIto", @"Jodido", @"Ala", @"Que pajita", @"Wuauau", @"Tengo hambrunita", @"jojolete", @"Sequito duro", @"Latititititito", @"Manusico"];

       **// Array which contains the other arrays**
      _arrayOfIngredients = @[@"_arrayOfBrasa, _arrayOfCeviche,_arrayOfChaufa"];

    }
```

Please help me with this problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Collection view has a delegate method didSelectItemAtIndexPath: which fires when user select the item. Use it to pass call the segue and pass the data:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender: indexPath];
}
```

and in prepareForSegue: pass the data:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath*)sender;

    DetailViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    dvc.Titulos = [_arrayOfIngredients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 }
}
```